# Pre-built square-grid maps?

Tags: fantasy, battle-map, online-resources

I will be running a 4e adventure tomorrow night.  The adventure will take place in Fallcrest.  One of the main sites will be a Raven Queen temple in the city.  I need to put together a map of the location, but I would love to simply use one that someone has already created.  Are there any sites that have good canned maps for a temple or other locations?  For example, I may also need a tavern as well.

While I'm running 4e, maps for any fantasy setting or system should be fine as long as they have a square grid (as opposed to a hex grid or no grid).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Wizards.com itself has a massive collection.

Finding exactly what you need can be tedious, but for sheer volume it's hard to beat the [wizards.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20140727063208/http://www.wizards.com/dnd/) galleries and archives.

The [Art & Map Gallery](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111213156/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/arch/ag) and the [Map-A-Week Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210828141728/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/arch/mw) are both free, and give access to most of the maps published in *D&D 3.5* physical volumes and adventures (though not the content that goes with them) as well as some bonus maps. If you have a D&D Insider subscription you can also access the [Article Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20151207112705/http://archive.wizards.com:80/DnD/Archive.aspx), which [has all the maps from the 4e *Dungeon* and *Dragon* Magazines](https://web.archive.org/web/20151003233653/http://archive.wizards.com/DnD/Archive.aspx?category=all&subcategory=MapGalleries).

Answer (score 9):

[Cartographer's Guild](http://www.cartographersguild.com) has a [wide](http://www.cartographersguild.com/picall.php) [selection](http://www.cartographersguild.com/albumall.php) of maps, some of which are gridded for tabletop gaming.

[Paratime Design](http://paratime.ca/cartography/bw_dungeons.html) released 100 Creative Commons licensed, black and white dungeon maps in the style of old D&D.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend that you also consider taking a look at the [dungeonmorphs](http://dungeonmorphs.com/) products. Rather than a map, they are like Legos for building maps in a moment or two. The dungeonmorphs are classic old-schoolish square-grid maps with exits from each tile at the same locations. So you can use the dice, cards, battlemat images, or fonts to create dungeons at high speed.

The dice are of good quality and really fun, but I think the cards present an amazing value, having all the dice images and their mirrors. The battlemats are free and the fonts are under $10.00.

So with these goodies, you can have a huge array of dungeons at your disposal, an array you can prep; or just roll, deal, or type out on the fly.